# How to get a user to input 10 letters, then stores these in a char array

Tags: c++

I've tried this, but I having no luck, I'm am looking to get user input 5 letters and then print them out.

```
string input = "";
const int max = 5;
char string[max] = { };
cout << "Please enter 5 letters: " << endl;
cin.getline(string, max, '\n');
cout << "Your letters :" << string[max];
```

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? What "is not working"?

Comment: i'm not getting any errors, but its skipping asking for the user to input letters and printing and output of `|}`

Comment: Perhaps it's a problem with having a `string` called `input` and also a `char[]` called `string`.

Comment: Please try not to use variable names that are keywords.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out what's not working:

First, you are printing out `string[max]` at the end. Since `string` is a `char[]` of size `max`, it actually has no data at index `max`--its indices are `0` to `max-1`. You are actually printing out a random character from whatever happens to be in memory immediately after the characters of your `string` variable.

So instead of `<< string[max]` in the last line, it should be `<< string`.

Second, after making that change, it will still seem to print only 4 characters, instead of the 5 that were entered. This is because strings in the form of `char[]`s have a null terminator. So since you are telling `cin.getline` to only fill up 5 characters in `string`, it fills the first 4 with actual characters from input, and then the last character is `'\0'`.

So if the input is `"hello"`, then `string` will contain the following values: `{ 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', '\0' }`. And then when you print it, there are, of course, really only 4 characters in the array.

And two notes: `string input` is not used anywhere in your program, so it should be taken out of the question. And also, you really should call your `char string[max]` variable something else, to reduce confusion.

I hope this helps!